# Two way data binding in isolated child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a form which contains a fieldset, Form can have varying number of this fieldset, so I have a add more button in the form. There can be a situation where form has no fieldset. To fulfill these requirements I need have directive inheritance. The fieldset directive will be added on button click event. Fieldset has a template but the actual input fields HTML string is coming from server on page load. therefore I need to complete fieldset on the fly by appending input boxes with different id and then add this fieldset to the form.

To explain this scenario better I have scaled down my implementation and have created below code snippet and here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/41gHYEVxG9CIUGduDPwI?p=preview).

In scaled down scenario only form-Dir directive exist on page load. This directive has a button to fields with increasing id.

```
<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div form-dir this-page="page" bind-field-id = "fieldId" bind-first-name="firstName" >
            This is {{page}} page
            <button class='btn-add'> add isolated fields </button>
            <div class='field'>

            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Script

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.page = "Demo"
    $scope.fieldId = "2"
    $scope.firstName = "John"


});

app.directive("formDir", function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict:'A',
        transclude: false,
        scope:{
            page:"=thisPage",
            id:"=bindFieldId",
            firstName:"=bindFirstName"
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.page = 'demo2';

            element.find('.btn-add').bind('click', function(e){
                var field = angular.element(e.currentTarget).siblings('.field')

                var newScope = scope.$new();

                var ele = '<field-dir bind-field-id = "id" bind-first-name="firstName"></field-dir>';

                var directive = $compile(ele)(newScope);

                field.append(directive);

                console.log('btn clicked', field)
            })
        }
    };
});

app.directive("fieldDir", function() {

    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            id:"=bindFieldId",
            firstName:"=bindFirstName"
        },
        template: '<div></div>',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){

            element.append('<label>{{scope.id}} First Name fields </label>'
                +' <input type="text" class="textbox" ng-model="firstName">'
                +' <button class="btn-change">change first name</button>');

            element.find('.btn-change').bind('click', function(e){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.firstName = "Doe";
                    scope.id = parseInt(scope.id) + 1;
                });


                console.log(scope)
            })

        }
    };
});
```

The code will work if I place `label`,`input` and `button` tags in template; but as per my scenario I need to append it. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  All I needed to do is $compile before appending HTML string field.

replace

```
element.append('<label>{{scope.id}} First Name fields </label>'
 +' <input type="text" class="textbox" ng-model="firstName">'
 +' <button class="btn-change">change first name</button>');
```

with

```
var r = $compile('<label>{{id}} First Name fields </label>'
    +' <input type="text" class="textbox" ng-model="firstName">'
    +' <button class="btn-change">change first name</button>')(scope)

element.append(r);
```